# Using CSS Float property with Google Visualization Charts

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have several Pie Charts made using Google Visualization tools and a PHP backend server.  Works just fine.

However, if I add a simple inline style to the container div (specifically the float:left style) the chart loses all interactivity.  It draws fine, it just won't highlight anything when there is a mouse-over or popup with a tooltip (normal GVis behavior).

Basically, I was wondering what was happening technically, and what would be a workaround.  The end result should be two pie charts side-by-side with a third one below.

Thanks.

---

Here's the working Div structure and CSS markup for future posterity.

```
<div id="firstLineofCharts">
  <div id="chart1" style="display:inline-block; width:400px; height:350px;"></div>
  <div id="chart2" style="display:inline-block; width:400px; height:350px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="secondLineofCharts" style="float:clear"></div>
```

Obviously you can convert this to full CSS Markup using the id's and classes.

Comment: could you paste sample code that generates it, and the relevant html/css on your page?

Comment: Can you share exactly the CSS fix that you had. I'm trying to do the same thing and cant figure out which class to add the display: inline-block; to. Thanks.

Comment: Edited question to answer @MikeSimmons comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do a clearfix afterwards? Alternatively, you can apply the following style to the div and compare its effect:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I had already had a clear on the next div down.  I changed it to the suggested "display: inline-block" and that worked just fine.  Thanks.  Any ideas why float doesn't work?

Comment: No idea. I haven't worked with GVis myself, so I wouldn't know. Maybe a shot in the dark, but perhaps there's a script that renders an extra layer for interaction on top, so doing float might somehow be messing up the flow of the layout?

Comment: That makes some sense.  Thanks.