# Google Chart in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart to display the results.  But i need to display the charts side by side

Like

```
    1st Chart                 2nd  Chart                     3rd chart.
```

I.e Basically i need to fix the Chart location.  I tried in lot of ways, but its not working.  ( I tried CSS, but not sure how to control google chart in that).

It displaying like one below one.

So i provide the code to somebody will help me.  Please note( DB connection and other things i didn't provide,

Php code for SQL:

INDEX.PHP invokes the below 2 PHPs, and I didn't provide the DB connect information.

SQLQUERY.PHP

```
<?PHP 
mysql_select_db("Loan_Bids", $con); 

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT A.Interest_Rate, A.Bid_Size, B.Rating from bids_data A, loan_data B Where A.LoanID = B.LoanID");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

CHARTDET.PHP

php code for Chart.

```
<?php

$rows = array();
$rows1 = array();
$rows2 = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table1 = array();
$table2 = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Interest_Rate', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Bid_Size', 'type' => 'number')
);

$table1['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Interest_Rate', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Bid_Size', 'type' => 'number')
);

$table2['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Interest_Rate', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Bid_Size', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
$rows1 = array();
$rows2 = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

    $Ratingval = $r['Rating'];

    if ($Ratingval == 1 ) 
    {   $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Scatter Chart for Rating 1
       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Interest_Rate']); 
    // Values of each slice
       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Bid_Size']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    } 
    else 
        {
            if ($Ratingval == 2 ) 
            {
                $temp1 = array();
            // the following line will be used to slice the Scatter Chart for Rating 2
                $temp1[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Interest_Rate']); 
            // Values of each slice
                $temp1[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Bid_Size']); 
                $rows1[] = array('c' => $temp1);
            } 
            else 
            {
               $temp2 = array();
            // the following line will be used to slice the Scatter Chart for Rating 2
                $temp2[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Interest_Rate']); 
            // Values of each slice
                $temp2[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Bid_Size']); 
                $rows2[] = array('c' => $temp2);
            }
        }    

}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

$table1['rows'] = $rows1;
$jsonTable1 = json_encode($table1);

$table2['rows'] = $rows2;
$jsonTable2 = json_encode($table2);

?>

 <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Rating 1',
          is3D: 'true',
          color:'red',
          hAxis: {title: 'Interest Rate'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Bid Size'},
          width:200,height:200
   };

       var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable1?>);
      var options1 = {
           title: 'Rating 2',
          is3D: 'true',
          hAxis: {title: 'Interest Rate'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Bid Size'},
          width:200,height:200
          };

    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable2?>);
      var options2 = {
           title: 'Rating 3',
          is3D: 'true',
          hAxis: {title: 'Interest Rate'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Bid Size'},
          width:200,height:200
          };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

      var chart1 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
      chart1.draw(data1, options1);

      var chart2 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
      chart2.draw(data2, options2);       
 }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div1"></div>
    <div id="chart_div2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set the chart divs to float left in css? Perhaps you could set the divs to `inline-block`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412873/using-css-float-property-with-google-visualization-charts

Comment: Even i used that CSS Option its not showing.                           <style>
p {display:inline}
</style>


  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
<p>    <div id="chart_div"></div>   </p>
<p> <div id="chart_div1"></div>   </p>
<p> <div id="chart_div2"></div>   </p>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Did you try `inline-block`, it is not the same as `inline`.

Comment: No Luck <style>
p {display:inline-block; width:200px; }

</style>


  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
<p>    <div id="chart_div"></div>   </p>
<p> <div id="chart_div1"></div>   <p>
<p>       <div id="chart_div2"></div>   </p>
  </body>    It is still displaying one below one

Comment: Try to set the style on the actual div, not a `<p>` tag surrounding the div. `<style>#chart_div1,#chart_div2{ display:inline-block;}</style>`

Comment: You don't need to use `inline-block` `float: left;` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to float the container divs:

[CSS]

```
#chart_div1, #chart_div2, #chart_div3 {
    float: left;
}
```

[HTML]

```
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<div id="chart_div3"></div>
```

For this to work, the charts/divs have to be narrow enough to fit side-by-side.  By default, they draw at 100% width unless you override that in chart options or the CSS for the div.